# Отображается нажатая клавиша в методе Console.ReadKey() Visual Studio 2019 C#

Tags: c#, консоль, visual-studio-2019, key

Когда использую метод Console.ReadKey(); в консоль отображается нажатая клавиша. Как не отображать?
(ex. При нажатии ConsoleKey.F отображается 'а' в консоль)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Program
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй

Console.ReadKey(true);

Определяет, отображать ли нажатую клавишу в окне консоли. true не отображать нажатую клавишу; в противном случае false.

Comment: Помогло, спасибо!